# Getting Unauthenticated 401 in Ionic app while sending POST request with HttpHeaders

Tags: angular, api, rest, ionic-framework

I'm sending POST request with header info.

If I use the logout function, everything works well and the backend returns a 200 success status. If I use the function updateName, I keep getting a 401 Unauthenticated.

In both cases I'm sending the same access token to the backend.

Any insights or something I'm missing?

**users.service.ts**

```
  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',   
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem("access_token")
    }),
    observe : 'response' as 'response'
  };

updateName(data) {

    this.http.post(environment.getBaseAddress() + 'users/updateName', data, this.httpOptions).subscribe((data) =>  {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('current-location');
    });
  }

logout(){
    this.http.get(environment.getBaseAddress() + 'logout', this.httpOptions).subscribe((data) =>  {
      localStorage.removeItem("authToken");   
      localStorage.removeItem("access_token");
      if (localStorage.getItem("access_token") === null)  {
        console.log("access is now null" + localStorage.getItem("access_token"));
        console.log("auth is now null" + localStorage.getItem("access_token"))
        this.router.navigateByUrl("");
      }
      else console.log("error during removal") 
    });
  }
```

**error showing**

```
{"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null},"status":401,"statusText":"OK","url":"https://myserverinfo.com/api/users/updateName","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for https://myserverinfo.com/api/users/updateName: 401
```

Not sure if it helps, but logout is GET, and updateName is POST.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has nothing to do with ionic.
I am assuming since you are using the same access token for both GET and POST and getting 200,ok for GET and 401 for POST, that you have to change the ACL.
What kind of backend you are using?

Comment: I'm using Laravel.

Comment: Thank you for your response Haythem. Would you mind explaining why I'd need ACL?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was my this.httpOptions in the requests. Inserting the header details in the request itself. I rewrote the functions this way:

```
this.http.post(environment.getBaseAddress() + 'users/updateName', data, { headers: new HttpHeaders({
  'Content-Type':  'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem("access_token")
})}).subscribe((data) =>  {
  this.router.navigateByUrl('current-location');
  console.log(data)
},
```